# Scroll Percentage of Cell with offset

Tags: ios, swift

I have a list in Swift that is of length `L`.

I have a viewport of height `h`

The viewport has position `x` along the list.

I am trying to calculate the percentage scrolled of the list. Effectively when `x=0`, the scroll percentage is `0`. However, because the measurement point occurs at the top of the viewport, the list is `100%` scrolled when `x = L-h`. I am trying to create a formula to calculate the scroll percentage based off `x` but struggling to create an formula for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simply `percent = x / (L - h)`. This gives a value in the range `0.0` - `1.0`.